# What's the proper term for either incrementing or decrementing?

Tags: synonyms

Not so much a term for *each* but one that could account for either direction.

Comment: A sequential update? A unit change?

Comment: Unit change. For instance: Incrementing/decrementing a number by 1.

Comment: Most computing texts I've read say "incrementing or decrementing" or "incrementing/decrementing". "Unit change" could be ambiguous (it could mean converting between units of measurement), but it would depend on the context.

Comment: In strict maths parlance, it's simply 'addition'. 10 **+** 1 = 11; 10 **+** ˉ1 = 9.